# I am trying to decrease the width of a text using arrays in java, but java is returning a single error

Tags: java, arrays, fixed-width

I am trying to decrease the width of a text, and in line 19 of my code java returns the error cannot find symbol.  Here is my code up to the line containing the error:

```
public class FixedWidthPrinting{
  public static void print(String[] inputArray,int width){
    int wordCount,charCount,extraSpaces;
    int currentIndex=0;
    int[] spaceArray;
    boolean even=false;
    while(currentIndex<inputArray.length-1){
      wordCount=0;
      charCount=inputArray[currentIndex].length();
      for(int i=currentIndex+1;charCount+inputArray[i].length()+1<=width;i++){
        charCount+=(inputArray[i].length()+1);
        wordCount++;
        } 
          if(wordCount==0){
          spaceArray=new int[1];
          }else{
            spaceArray=new int[wordCount];
            }
      inputArray.fill(spaceArray,1);
```

The error:

FixedWidthPrinting.java:19: error: cannot find symbol
      inputArray.fill(spaceArray,1);
                ^
  symbol:   method fill(int[],int)
  location: variable inputArray of type String[]

Here is the rest of the code, could I possibly have an error in the rest of my code that is causing java to return this error?

```
extraSpaces=width-charCount;
      if(even==false){
        for(int i=0;i<spaceArray.length&&extraSpaces>0;i++){
          spaceArray[i]++;
          extraSpaces--;
          }
        even=true;
        }else{
      for(int i=spaceArray.length-1;i>=0&&extraSpaces>0;i--){
        spaceArray[i]++;
        extraSpaces--;
        }
      even=false;
      }
    System.out.print(inputArray[currentIndex]);
    currentIndex++;
    for(int i=0;wordCount>0;i++){
      for(int j=spaceArray[i];j>0;j--){
      System.out.print(" ");
      }
    System.out.print(inputArray[currentIndex]);
    wordCount--;
    currentIndex++;
    }
    System.out.println();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Well `inputArray`, is an array, not an `ArrayList`

Comment: So is there another command I can use in the place of inputArray.fill? I apologize if this is a silly question, I am quite lost with arrays right now.

Answer (score 0):

I thinks you want to use the method `fill` of `java.util.Arrays`

Do it like this :

```
Arrays.fill(spaceArray,1);
```

Comment: I replaced inputArray.fill with Arrays.fill, and java returned the same error                                      FixedWidthPrinting.java:19: error: cannot find symbol
      Arrays.fill(spaceArray,1);
      ^
  symbol:   variable Arrays
  location: class FixedWidthPrinting
1 error

Comment: You have to `import java.util.Arrays`

Comment: After that, the error changed to: main method not found in class FixedWidthPrinting

Comment: Your class must have a `main` method in order to be run.